# Get unpushed commits with libgit2

Tags: c++, c, git, version-control, libgit2

Is there a way to show all unpushed commits from all available branches with libgit 2. My idea was to use git_revparse(&spec, repo, "origin/master..master"); but this gives me a git_revspec and I don't know how to use this to iterate over all commits. Another problem is that this method is for a specific branch only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `git_branch_iterator` functions to get all of the local branches and `git_branch_upstream` to get their corresponding upstream branch. Then use the `git_revwalk` functions to walk over all of the commits that are different between them. Push the upstream with `git_revwalk_push_ref` and hide the local branch with `git_revwalk_hide_ref`.

Comment: RE "use the `git_revwalk`  functions each commit that is different for local vs upstream": can you point to or explain any examples of how to do this? libgit2 documentation and examples not clear at all on this, at least to me